C# Lambda => expressions failing in visual studio 2010 from reverse engineered DLL
So I reverse engineered a DLL using dotpeek from jetbrains and it wrote code that was too modern.   I was left with lambda => expressions which visual studio 2010 doesn't understand.  The goal of all of this is to replace a dll with editable source code.
I need to see how I can rewrite these statements without using the lambda.  Not included here, some of it I can rewrite, but I'm copy pasting what I don't understand how to rewrite.
1: public override string object_type => "access_token";
2: public override string resource => "/access_tokens";
3: public override string object_type => "account";
4: public override string resource => "/accounts";
5: public virtual string object_type => "";
6: public virtual string resource => "";
7: public override string object_type => "payment_method";
8: public override string resource => "/payment_methods";
9: public override string object_type => "transaction";
10: public override string resource => "/transactions";

It's statements of this nature that I don't understand.   All these statements are similar though, so if I can get the concept behind it, I should be able to replace all of them with more primitive statements to work in the older version of visual studio.
I tried running all these statements on an old server 2012 system based off a 2010 visual studio compiler but it both underlines the statements in red and fails on them.   I think this is because Lambda => statements are more modern than the technology being used to run the visual studio c# asp.net scripts.

These are expression-bodied properties (link)
For this expression:
public override string object_type => "access_token";

...the equivalent traditional property would be:
public override string object_type 
{
    get { return "access_token"; }
}

These should compile to the same thing.
But before you go manually editing these, I would suggest you see if JetBrains will let you choose. According to this page you can make that selection on Tools | Options | Decompiler | Code style and formatting.
